# JQuery get closest div to selected element

Tags: jquery, html

I have my HTML markup as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
      <select id="select" class="form-control voip_destination_select">
      <option>Select</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 voip_destination_number2">
  <div class="form-group">
      text
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in JQuery, I am checking for changes in the select element and from that, I want to find the next div with class `voip_destination_number2`

```
$('.voip_destination_select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('.voip_destination_number2').next('.voip_destination_number2')
});
```

*UPDATED HTML OPTION*

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
      <select id="select" class="form-control voip_destination_select">
      <option>Select</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="voip_destination_number2">
          text
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is close, but the issue is because `.voip_destination_number2` is not a parent of the `select` which raised the event, so the `closest()` call returns nothing.

To fix this you need to get the closest parent element which is a sibling of `.voip_destination_number2`, in this case `col-xs-6`, then use `next()`, like this:

```js
$('.voip_destination_select').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.voip_destination_number2').addClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="select" class="form-control voip_destination_select">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 voip_destination_number2">
  <div class="form-group">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only issue is, through out my code `col-xs-6` isnt going to be the same everywhere. would it be possible to just use the class `voip_destination_number2`

Comment: In which case you'd need to find another way to target that specific `div`, but the logic is the same. You could potentially go a level higher and use `find('.voip_destination_number2')` but this will only work if there's one of those elements contained within it.

Comment: what about swapping the class names and putting `voip_destination_number` first or wrapping the `col-xs-6` div inside another div with class `voip_destination_number`

Comment: That could potentially work. If you could update the question to show the HTML layout I'll update the answer for you

Comment: i'm wondering whether that will work, as i am dynamcially creating content inside the div i am trying to find

Comment: That would work, you just need to use `$(this).closest('.col-xs-6').next('.col-xs-6').find('.voip_destination_number2').addClass('foo');` instead

Comment: would you need to add the `form-group` class in there?

Comment: No, as `closest()` goes through all parent elements until it finds a match

Comment: its seeing it in the console, but not adding the class as per your code

Answer (score 0):

First you have to traverse up the DOM via [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to your div with class `col-xs-6` then go to its sibling via [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and then back down the DOM via [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Like this:

```
$('.voip_destination_select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.col-xs-6').next().find('.voip_destination_number2')
});
```